# Project's running fine on iPhone 4s simulator and throws some core data errors while running on 5/5s simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

Do you guys think is the Xcode 6 beta 3 thats acting weird ?
anybody having similar issues ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed something in the data model.you need to remove the app first from device or simulator and recompile.It has nothing to do with simulator or device.It is true that xcode 6 is not stable but this is not the cause.

Comment: tried doing that, still the same result.
To be precise, i am getting this error when running on 5/5s simulator.
"The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"
but runs fine on 4s simulator